# Where to set and layout a TableView footer

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to add a footer to my table view. The problem I'm having is:

If I set the footer in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, then that causes `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to be called and we end up in an infinite loop.

If instead I set the footer in `viewDidLoad` and calculate it and its subviews' frames in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, the footer ends up at the top of the table view covering up my first section.

I can't calculate the frames in `viewDidLoad` because the table view's bounds aren't right then (my app only supports landscape mode).

I can use a boolean instance variable to create and layout the footer view in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but only when it's first called, but that seems wrong. Then the frames won't ever be calculated again. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create them in `viewDidLoad` and assign them to the `tableViewHeader` and `tableViewFooter` properties, that way the tableview will handle their positioning.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried this too. The footer view has subviews that it lays out in layoutSubviews. So if I do it like that, the tableview's scroll bounds don't get adjusted and the footer view is below the bottom of the table view's scroll area

Comment: After you change the size of the footer view, reassign it to the tableViewFooter and things will get fixed.

Comment: The footer view's size gets changed in willLayoutSubviews and reassigning it as the footer there causes willLayoutSubviews to be called again. Same with viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: So you're changing the size of the footer as a result of layout?  That sounds like a really bizarre thing to be doing.  I'd expect it to be dependent on the data or fixed.

Comment: To break the infinite loop can you compute the new size and only set it if it actually changes?

Comment: I can do that and it works and I will if I can't do something that seems less hacky. But if this sounds bizarre to you maybe I am doing something hacky in the first place that is at the root of this. This is how i see it. The footer has a label in it and it wants all of its views to be centered. Therefore it needs to know what width it will be displayed in to calculate the proper frames for the label and other subviews. So in viewWillLayoutSubviews the TableViewController tells the footer what its width will be, the footer lays out its subviews and tells the TVC what height it wants.

Comment: Then the new frame is set according to that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to subclass UIView for the footer and override `sizeThatFits:` and `layoutSubviews` there.  That should alleviate the whole problem.  views really shouldn't change size in layoutSubviews, just ... well... layout their subviews :)

Comment: You're right, I just went and read up on sizeThatFits and layoutSubviews and implemented it as best I could and somehow setting the table view's footer in viewWillLayoutSubviews magically doesn't cause an infinite loop anymore. I don't quite understand it but it works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The primary reason it works is that it separates out size computation (sizeThatFits:) and layout (layoutSubviews) into separate steps.  UITableView calls sizeThatFits: to ask how big the footer then needs to be and sizes it as part of it's own layoutSubviews.  Once that's done it calls your layoutSubviews to actually layout the contents.